# The concept of user and application association in AAD

Tags: azure-active-directory

In my Azure subscription, when I go to a user’s profile, I have the Applications section as shown below:

[image]

1. Is this list a mechanism to give users permission to use an application, or give applications permission to access user’s data or both?
2. How exactly applications are added here?
3. Is there any way Administrators can assign applications to this user, like how Group assignment work?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Is this list a mechanism to give users permission to use an
>   application, or give applications permission to access user’s data or
>   both?

The specific screenshot you have shared is a read-only/informational page which shows applications that are assigned to this user (say explicitly by an admin) or this user has consented for.

(NOTE: Things in Azure Portal keep getting updated so exact functionality possible in this page may change in future, but overall concept should probably stay the same).

At a high level your statement about giving user permission to use this application or give application permission to access user's data or both is correct. Only thing is actions are done elsewhere, while this page is showing results/information.

> How exactly applications are added here?

a. When a user is explicitly assigned to an application. One way for an admin to do that is to navigate to the specific application. Azure Portal > Azure Active Directory > Enterprise Applications > Specific Application > Users and Groups > Add User

[image]

b. User navigates directly to application and at the time of signing in user is presented with a consent screen where they consent to application's required permissions etc.

> Is there any way Administrators can assign applications to this user,
>   like how Group assignment work?

From Azure portal, administrators can navigate to the application directly (in enterprise application section) > Users and Groups and then create assignments for this application. Yes it's similar to Group assignment. Group assignments require a particular level of Azure AD plan though. Individual users can be assigned even with the free version. Please refer to screenshot in answer for 2nd question, part a above.

A couple of related application settings that you may be interested in -

[image]

'User assignment required' as the name suggests controls whether only explicitly assigned users can access the application or any user can.

'Visible to users' controls whether application is visible in  O365 app launcher and Access panel or not.

Hover over the i sign for more detailed information on these settings.

Comment: Thank you for the comprehensive answer.